# Unable to deserialize System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException

Tags: c#, mef

I have an MEF project which is causing me problems that I can't seem to trace. It was working fine until I had to update one of the project files that seems to have caused everything to break. It's throwing `CompositionException`, but since the object that has the MEF contained is in another AppDomain, what I see is actually:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
>
> The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException' was not found.

As it turns out `CompositionException` isn't (de)serializable so I lose any chance to figure out what's wrong with it. Is there a way around this problem? I've been unable to trap the exception on the other side so that I can see it there.

What I have is something like this:

```
public class MyCollection
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;
    private AggregateCatalog catalog;
    private DirectoryCatalog dirCatalog;

    [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true, RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IItem, ItemInfo>> Items{ get; private set; }

    public MyCollection(string path)
    {
        catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(searchPath);
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);
        _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        try
        {
            _container.ComposeParts(this);                
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            throw;    // Note: this does not get hit
        }

        // this is added just for debugging
        foreach (var s in Items)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{s.Metadata.Name} ({s.Metadata.Version}) is good!");
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionException)
            {
                // this never gets hit either
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{s.Metadata.Name} is bad!!!!");
            }
        }
        // end debugging
    }
}
```

I create the `MyCollection` object in an AppDomain like this:

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    CachePath = cachePath,
    ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
    ShadowCopyDirectories = pluginPath
};

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Host_AppDomain", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

var collection = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            typeof(MyCollection).Assembly.FullName,
            typeof(MyCollection).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Default, null, new object[] { pluginPath }, null, null) as MyCollection;

// everything is fine so far...

foreach (var s in collection.Items)   // fails on collection.Items
{
    // the loop is never entered
    Console.WriteLine($"{s.Metadata.Name} - {s.Metadata.Version}");
}
```

So in my code calling `Items` it fails despite it being the exact same loop that caused no problems inside `MyCollection` and with the `SerializationException` being thrown the original exception get eaten.

I'm sure the problem is ultimately that one of the imported assemblies didn't get updated, but I have no way of figuring out which one is the offender.

Comment: Why do you create the Collection in another AppDomain?

Comment: Because it's necessary for shadow copy to work. You can't turn on shadow copy in an existing AppDomain, you have to create one with shadow copy. Then `MyCollection` has to be *in that AppDomain* but I need to be able to interact with it from the original parent AppDomain.

Comment: Is your Collection serializable?

Comment: Yes. That's not the problem. The problem is that `CompositionException` isn't serializable.

Comment: You could try to divide Property and Field of your Items Property. Then you could catch the Exception in the get-Section of the Property.